# C# SQL Server: Query that use a numeric string in a where clause does not work properly

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a column RES_LOCALIZADOR which is a numeric string.. it should be a bigint though.

When executing this query, although it doesnt fail, it doesnt return any value when it should. I have added CAST fucntion to prevent an error I had before (The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column in sql server)

```
            var str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine(" SELECT WEB_codigo ");
        str.AppendLine(" FROM[intranetMinorista].[dbo].[RESERVA] R WITH(NOLOCK) ");
        long value = 206627660;
        str.AppendFormat(" WHERE CAST(RES_LOCALIZADOR AS BIGINT)=" +value);
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You should use parameterization. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements). It not only protects against sql injection, it also handles datatypes better. Did you try to execute the query in SSMS?

Comment: Even though parameters are good and all I doubt they will improve the situation in this specific case... `long.ToString()` is not the typical producer of injection code. I would also be interested in the SSMS result. I'm not using SQL server to much... is it legal to have `FROM[intranetMinorista]` without a space after `FROM`?

Comment: What happens if you select the data a "select web_codigo, CAST(RES_LOCALIZADOR AS BIGINT) from [intranetMinorista].[dbo].[RESERVA]" do you see the values you epect?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have changed to use parametrizacion but still doesnt work. The SSMS result is ok, it returns the value I expect.

Comment: @BugFinder by doing so, it works, it returns good results, it looks like the problem is with values in the WHERE cluase. In my case, the problem is with a VARCHAR that contains numeric values.  Also I am havving same problem with BIGINT.  IT works fine with int column.

Comment: why would you store numeric values that you wish to use in a string field?

Comment: Can you have a look in the profiler to check the actual query send to the database?

Comment: Off-topic; [no lock](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) can return unpredictable results.  However, doubt that is the issue here.

Comment: @BugFinder thanks, can you please let me know where is the profiler? i am new with Visual Studio

Comment: I assume that last comment was directed at me. I don't know where or if Visual Studio has a database profiler, but if you are in SQL Server Management Studio you'll find it under the "Tools" menu. It lists all queries which are fired at the database.

Comment: Can you please include the exact query text that is working inside SSMS into your question?

Comment: @grek40 Hi Greg, I have just placed the queries I am having problems with.  They work on SSMS but not when executing from the code

Comment: Please edit the new information into the question and remove the answer. What was the error that you got without the `CAST`? You should ONYL EVER compare the same query in Code and SSMS. Your current question query is different, which makes all comparison useless.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.. It looks like there is a problem with that table.. the clien I am working for have a bit of chaos.  I have tried in other tables and work fine. Not sure what can affect that particular table..Anyway, appreciate evyerone looking at this

Answer (score -1):

SELECT WEB_codigo FROM [intranetMinorista].[dbo].[RESERVA] WHERE RES_localizador = 206627660

RES_localizador IS A VARCHAR IN BDDD

Also I am having problems when the column is of type BIGINT 
SELECT WEB_codigo FROM [intranetMinorista].[dbo].[RESERVA] WHERE RES_CODIGO = 20946346

Res_codigo is a bigint in BBDD

Comment: Please edit your question to add information, new information shouldn't be a comment, even less an answer. What is BDDD/BBDD?